# Django - sending lots of emails -- SMTP connection dropping

Tags: django, gmail, sendmail

I have an app that sends upwards of 1,000 emails to clients. Each email is customized per the client. I have my Django app using my Gmail Business account (paid for Google App) to send emails.

The problem I have is that after around 80-100 emails being sent successfuly, the SMTP connection to Gmail drops. I have to wait about 10-15 minutes before I can start sending again. But, again after about 70-100 emails sending properly, the connection is dropped.

I use Django-Mailer-2 to send mail. Here is the error that my Django app produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_mailer/management/commands/send_mail.py", line 47, in handle_noargs
    send_all(block_size, backend=settings.USE_BACKEND)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_mailer/engine.py", line 91, in send_all
    blacklist=blacklist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_mailer/engine.py", line 179, in     send_queued_message
    [message.to_address], smart_str(message.encoded_message))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 697, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 438, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 363, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 340, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Those last two lines make me think that Gmail is closing the connection. I have contaced Gmail, and they claim that it is my sofware that is causing the problem, not them.

What do you think?

Comment: Have you tried a telnet session on google mailservice when your connection drops? Just to verifiy the possibility of connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK -- I solved this situation. Really, it is more of a work around. I believe that Gmail is stopping my emails because they think it is spam. Sending hundreds of emails one after the other has triggered something on their end and closed my connection. That's my theory anyway.

My work around is adding a line of code to the `engine.py` file. After an email is sent successfully, I added the line `time.sleep(70)`. This causes the mailer to simply wait 70 seconds before continuing. I added this code and tried sending all my emails. After about 7 hours, over 400 emails were sent successfully. I would say that it works. It doesn't have to be fast, it just has to work. I wouldn't care if it took a few days -- so long as they are sent.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  I've taken your solution, but instead of sleeping after every email, I send 10 emails then wait 70 seconds.  I was able to successfully send over 200 emails this way.  When I tried sleeping every 50 emails, I still had the problem, and only 100 emails were sent before the connection was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you most likely can only do some debugging:
"/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", around line 697 looks like this:

```
    (code,resp) = self.mail(from_addr, esmtp_opts)
    if code != 250:
        self.rset()
        raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
```

To me it looks like the server handles the RSET command by canceling the connection. You could try if that's the case. By handling a connection manually and issuing the rset() command.

Also this code seems to be called before raising the SMTPSenderRefused exception, so this specific mail would not be sent anyway.

A quick fix might be a monkey patch, to disable the RSET command:

```
import smtplib
smtplib.SMTP.rset = lambda self: 0
```

Comment: This is not very good idea, becauce connection refused by server and this monkey patching will not have any effect.

Comment: Well, it will at least give appropriate feedback on what caused the reset in the first place by raising the appropriate exception. A smarter patch could be `smtplib.SMTP.rset = smtplib.SMTP.close` to also close the socket, which might allow an immediate reconnect.

Comment: @rumpel: I'll give the `smtplib.SMTP.close` a try and report back. You are right about the emails not even being sent. In my dialogue with the Gmail support, they keep asking for headers from the emails that are affected and I keep saying, "Emails aren't affected, the connection is."

Comment: @rumpel: Well, I added that line and had the same result. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is some rate limit on the Google'd side. I found this email thread, discussing the problem: http://blogoscoped.com/forum/112956.html

Comment: I know there are limits. For our paid-for service (Google Business Apps) the limit is 2,000 emails per 24hours. I am not hitting that limit at all. Further, each email I send is unique -- thus the "more than 500 recipients" does not apply.